# Trigger in Oracle to auto-increment a field and insert into association table

Tags: database, oracle, triggers, oracle11g

I have a one-to-many relationship between two tables:

```
table1:

NUMBER users_id (primary key)
field2
field3
...

table2:

NUMBER users_id (foreign key)
VARCHAR2 name
...
...
```

and when I `INSERT` into `table1`, I want to auto increment (sequence?) `users_id` and insert a number of records into `table2` all with the same `users_id` so I end up with

```
table1:

1,val1,val2

table2:

1,barry,...
1,bob,...
1,james,...
```

I think I need a trigger with a sequence to auto-increment `users_id` in `table1` and create the rows in  `table2`.

It might not be relevant but I'm doing this from a PHP script.

**UPDATE**

So far I have a sequence and a trigger set up so I can `INSERT` into `table1` and have the `users_id` field auto-increment:

```
create sequence user_seq 
start with 1 
increment by 1 
nomaxvalue;

create trigger user_trigger
before insert on table1
for each row
begin
select user_seq.nextval into :new.users_id from dual;
end;
```

so now I just need to automatically insert into the second table.

Many thanks.

Comment: You want to insert only users_id into table2?

Comment: No, I would like to also insert a number of `name` values into `table2` but need the `users_id` too so I have an association.  Many thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP but there is a `returning clause` in a an insert statement that can return the id (which was just inserted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `returning into` clause of the `insert` statement to return `users_id` value after a new record has been inserted into `table1`. Also you can use `user_seq.currval` to get the current value of the sequence. Here is an example (In this example a simple stored procedure has been implemented to demonstrate the usage of `insert into` clause. You can implement a similar stored procedure according to your requirements):

```
SQL> create table Tb_table_1(
  2    user_id number primary key,
  3    field_1 number
  4  );

Table created

SQL> 
SQL> create table Tb_table_2(
  2    user_id number references tb_table_1(user_id),
  3    name1 varchar2(17)
  4  );

Table created

SQL> create sequence user_seq
  2  start with 1
  3  increment by 1
  4  nomaxvalue;

Sequence created

SQL> 
SQL> create trigger user_trigger
  2  before insert on tb_table_1
  3  for each row
  4  begin
  5    select user_seq.nextval into :new.user_id from dual;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created

  SQL> create or replace procedure Insert_Record
  2  is
  3    l_cur_id number;
  4  begin
  5    insert into Tb_table_1(Field_1)
  6      values(123)
  7    returning user_id into l_cur_id; -- store user_id of the new inserted record
  8    for i in 1..5                    -- in a local variable for later use  
  9    loop
 10      insert into tb_table_2(user_id, name1)  -- insert a bunch of sample data into table2 using previously stored user_id.
 11        values(l_cur_id, dbms_random.string('l', 7));
 12    end loop
 13    commit;
 14  end;
 15  /

Procedure created

SQL> select * from tb_table_1;

   USER_ID    FIELD_1
---------- ----------

SQL> select * from tb_table_2;

   USER_ID NAME1
---------- -----------------



SQL> exec insert_record;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> select * from tb_table_1
  2  ;

   USER_ID    FIELD_1
---------- ----------
         1        123

SQL> select * from tb_table_2;

   USER_ID NAME1
---------- -----------------
         1 jzsdbna
         1 ozbibgs
         1 btxrxcm
         1 hxwwpzc
         1 sdjbwzi

SQL>
```

In Oracle 11g onward you can directly assign sequence value to a variable:

```
:new.users_id := user_seq.nextval;
```

Comment: PERFECT.  Thank you.  Marking as 'solved' and +1 because I learned many new things about Oracle from just this script (I come from a MySQL background)