# how do i create a second auto increment column mysql with a default value that increases each time a new user is inserted

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want each user to have an auto incremented id (which is already the primary key) and a second address which should be a four digit code with the default value 0000. When the first user information is inserted 0000 is auto incremented. The process should continue for each insertion. However i cannot set two auto increment columns in my database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Trigger for it. `AFTER INSERT`. Example of after insert trigger is given below. Replace your code changes according to your work.

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT
   ON table_name
   [ FOR EACH ROW ]

DECLARE
   -- variable declarations

BEGIN
   -- trigger code

EXCEPTION
   WHEN ...
   -- exception handling

END;
```

you can get an idea about auto increment triggers by navigating answer of this [Trigger in Oracle to auto-increment a field and insert into association table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109740/trigger-in-oracle-to-auto-increment-a-field-and-insert-into-association-table) stackoverflow question

I think this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35449/how-to-use-2-auto-increment-columns-in-mysql-phpmyadmin also same question that u asked. you can improve your knowledge by browsing this.

Comment: would the trigger name be the name of the column?

Comment: Trigger name can be any name u want